# Remove Stop words in neo4j using text file

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I loaded CSV file in neo4j successfully, I want to remove stop words in the data set. I have separate stop words list in a text file. I found an example code using stop words. But I want to replace it with my stopwords list. How do I need to proceed? Can we load 2 data sets(kbv5.txt and stopwords.txt) in one query?

I want to include stop word list file in my code:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///kbv5.txt"  as row fieldterminator "."
with row
unwind row as text
with reduce(t=tolower(text), delim in 
["","",",",".","!","?",'"',":",";","'","-"] | replace(t,delim,"")) as 
normalized
with [w in split(normalized," ") | trim(w)] as words
unwind range(0,size(words)-2) as idx
MERGE (w1:Word {name:words[idx]})
ON CREATE SET w1.count = 1
ON MATCH SET w1.count = w1.count + 1
MERGE (w2:Word {name:words[idx+1]})
ON CREATE SET w2.count = 1
ON MATCH SET w2.count = w2.count + (case when idx = size(words)-2 then 1 
else 0 end)
MERGE (w1)-[r:NEXT]->(w2)
 ON CREATE SET r.count = 1 ON MATCH SET r.count = r.count +1
```

Example Code for using Stopwords:

```
with "Great device, but the calls drop too frequently." as text
with replace(replace(tolower(text),".",""),",","") as normalized
with [w in split(normalized," ") | trim(w)] as words
with [w in words WHERE NOT w IN ["the","an","on"]] as words
UNWIND range(0,size(words)-2) as idx
MERGE (w1:Word {name:words[idx]})
MERGE (w2:Word {name:words[idx+1]})
MERGE (w1)-[:NEXT]->(w2)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

This code demonstrates how you can remove stopwords from your text.  Try it out; it's won't write anything to your database.  You would do this near the top of your code, immediately after your import.

```
WITH SPLIT('some of these words are unnecessary',' ') AS text, 
     SPLIT('are but of in the these',' ') AS stopwords
RETURN FILTER (word IN text WHERE NOT word IN stopwords)
```